# "Naive Bayes" or "Naïve Bayes" issue in my thesis

Tags: fonts

I'm revising my thesis. I'm in a U.S.A university (American English).

My Prof asks me to change "Naive Bayes" to "Naïve Bayes" in my thesis. However, things are not easy.

First thing is that how to add two dots above i. I solved this issue by using Microsoft Word, where "Naive" can be automatically converted to "Naïve". Then I copy it and paste to the Texmaker and run the LaTeX.

[image]

But the result is not what I want

[image]

Comment: Use `Na\"ive` and it should go well.

Comment: If you're curious, the reason you got the weird output when putting "Naïve" into your document directly: in Unicode the character `ï` is [U+00EF LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH DIAERESIS](https://codepoints.net/U+00EF), which in the UTF-8 encoding is encoded by a sequence of two bytes: `C3` (195) followed by `AF` (175). Without `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` this gets interpreted as two 8-bit characters. In the [T1 font encoding](http://www.micropress-inc.com/fonts/encoding/t1.htm) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cork_encoding&oldid=774992370)), C3 is `Ã` and AF is `ŕ`.

Comment: And I  think the first question was not answered, Naive Bayes is correct not Naïve Bayes.

Comment: @samcarter I'm so sorry because I was so busy writing my graduate dissertation during that time, and I traveled for a long time after graduation. I would like to express my gratitude and appreciation to all the people who had helped me and I have accepted all my questions now. Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Either use

```
Na\"ive
```

or add

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

to your preamble, which will allow you to type

```
Naïve
```

Note that the longer `Na\"{\i}ve` is not required, unless your output encoding is T2A or similar that doesn't fully support the Latin alphabet.

### Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

Na\"ive

Na\"{\i}ve

Naïve

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The first proposal did not work for me. “na\"{\i}ve” produces a correct “naïve”, while “na\"{i}ve” in text mode yields i with 3 dots above the stick! See http://hevea.inria.fr/examples/test/sym.html

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko What TeX distribution are you running?

Comment: I use the up-to-date TUG distribution.

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko Your edit was unnecessary; and now I added an explicit example that shows `Na\"ive` works as stated. If it doesn't work in your setup, please ask a question with the necessary details. But you probably have `\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}`.

Comment: With LaTeX release 2018-04-01 or later, `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is not necessary any longer (when, of course, the document is UTF-8 encoded).

Comment: I get a chktex warning (7) when I use `na\"ive`. See http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/systems/doc/chktex/ChkTeX.pdf

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian Complain with `chktex` developers; the syntax `\"i` has been in use for more than 25 years, is correct and way simpler than `\"{\i}`.